# Morphing between images

Tags: image-processing, animation, neural-networks

With Mathematica it is possible to continuously morph between images of different faces. But I was wondering if it is also possible to morph between images of any kind?

An example that uses Artbreeder can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LR5f3-5vB_U):